# Blackberry Q10 SIM card in New Zealand

Tags: cellphones, new-zealand, data-plans

I will be visiting NZ this coming January and I would like to know if I will be able to get a SIM card that will work in my Blackberry Q10 while I am there?

Comment: For questions like this, it helps to mention which carrier originally provided the phone and from which country, as phones often get customized for different markets.

Answer (score 3):

The BlackBerry Q10 was actually sold in [five different models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_Q10#Model_comparison), with their [radio bands](http://www.gsmarena.com/blackberry_q10-5274.php) customized by which carriers sold them. While all of them will give you basic voice coverage in New Zealand, not all of them will give you 3G or 4G coverage.

Look up your specific model number on the box that the phone came in, on the label behind the battery, or in the System Settings > About > General menu category. It starts with SQN100- followed by a single digit from 1 to 5:

1. This phone was sold by AT&T in the US and Bell in Canada. In NZ it will only be assured to get 3G service with Spark due to its limited 3G frequencies (Spark is on 850/2100, Vodafone and 2degrees are on 900/2100). With other carriers 3G may be slower, spotty or nonexistent. It will not do 4G with any NZ carrier.
2. This phone was sold by Verizon Wireless in the US. It will do 3G with all NZ carriers, but will not do 4G with any carrier.
3. This phone was sold in Europe, Australia and the Middle East by a wide variety of carriers. It will do 3G and 4G with all NZ carriers (on LTE band 3), though 4G may not be available in all areas that a phone originally sold in NZ may pick up (as it lacks LTE band 28).
4. This phone was sold by Sprint in the US. It will do 3G with all NZ carriers, but will not do 4G with any carrier.
5. This phone was sold by T-Mobile in the US and several smaller Canadian carriers.  In NZ it will only be assured to get 3G service with Spark due to its limited 3G frequencies. With other carriers 3G may be slower, spotty or nonexistent. It will not do 4G with any NZ carrier.

Also sourced for this answer: [List of LTE networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LTE_networks); [List of UMTS networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UMTS_networks)